# What is wrong with this date and time?

Tags: r

I am using `R 3.4.2` but the same error was happening in `R 3.4.0`. Apparently it is a bug, but I wish to know if someone else also gets the same error. Maybe it is something specific of my machine. I am using Windows 7, so I don't know if the same occurs in other OS:

```
# OK
as.POSIXct("2014-10-18 00:01",tz = "America/Sao_Paulo")
[1] "2014-10-18 00:01:00 -03"

# NOT OK
as.POSIXct("2014-10-19 00:01",tz = "America/Sao_Paulo")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Daylight savings time: see [Time Change 2014 in Brazil](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil?year=2014)

Comment: Just a guess but I think this is an invalid time error. Did they set their clocks ahead in this time zone on 10/19/14? If so, it's possible that 12:01 am did not exist. You'd have to know the time zone jurisdiction rules to be sure. Edit - OK based on @RuiBarradas comments they actually set their clocks back, so this is ambiguous rather than invalid. In other words 12:01 am happened twice so there's no way to know what the time reference actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This date, Oct 19, 2014 was the day for moving the clocks back to end Daylight Savings Time.  Sao Paulo changes the clock at 1AM (back to midnight)  so this date/time means two different times.  It is ambiguous.  see [Daylight Savings Time in Sao Paulo](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2014)